# Save Information Bloc Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

This is a what is the best practice kind of a question.

I am working on a user login . Used bloc for login events like loginInProgress, UserNameValidation , PasswordValidation and LoginSuccess.
Now after login I have huge set of data in terms of JSON response to store locally via database and shared preferences. I named this info sort of as session storage. This information have also multiple filter operations before storing in database or shared preferences.So means I have to first get relative data from the information then it will be ready to save. I am using repository pattern to get data. Now I am confused that should this information storage process or code will be written in repository file or it will be in same BLOC class of Login or it will be a separate Session Manager class.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no "right" solution to this problem, it depends on the current architecture of your app. However, this is how I would handle this:

1. BLoC will call an `AuthService` that will handle all the required logic;
2. `AuthService` will be responsible for:

   - Fetching data from the database - use the related repository for this;
   - Do all the related mapping;
   - Store whatever is needed in local storage (e.g. Shared preferences);
   - Return the needed object to BLoC.
3. BLoC now has the needed data, so it's only responsible to set the right state.

This way, your BLoC only depends on the `AuthService` - it should be easy to test the BLoC logic.

`AuthService` depends on the repository (where you get the user data from) and also is responsible for handling all the related mapping as well as storing whatever is needed to `SharedPreferences`. Again, to test the `AuthService`, you would only need to mock the repository and the `SharedPreferences` instance.